# HTML/CSS navbar not working

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar, center

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS. I am working on a side project to help me practice. In the gif you can see a few problems with my navbar.

1. The navbar does not fill up the whole screen.

   > (I think this is because I have it set to "float: left" but when I set it to "float: center" the navbar is no longer inline but displayed as a list.)
2. The text in the navbar isn't in the center of their respective bubbles. I have a hover effect, the image that pops up is in the center, but the text isn't.

   > (I have it set to "text-align: center" but I think it has something to do with the  "float: left".

I have attached my html and css files.

[image: Website Bugs]

**Test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header id="main-header">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav id="navbar">
        <!--<div class="container">-->
            <ul>
                <li class="home-icon"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="rout-icon"><a href="#">Routines</a></li>
                <li class="nutr-icon"><a href="#">Nutrition</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Meals</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Diet Plans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calorie Tracking</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="abou-icon"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="cont-icon"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        <!--</div>-->
    </nav>

    <footer id="main-footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 Test</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

**Test.css**

```
body {
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    font-family: 'Saturday Sans ICG Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Saturday Sans ICG Bold";
    src: url("Fonts/Saturday Sans ICG Bold.tff");
    src: url("Fonts/saturday_sans_icg_bold-webfont.woff");
}

#main-header {
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Saturday Sans ICG Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navbar a {
    color: #A9A9A9;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

#navbar ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#navbar ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border-top: 2px #f4f4f4 solid;
    border-bottom: 2px #f4f4f4 solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
}

#navbar ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}

#navbar ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
}

#navbar ul li ul li:hover {
    opacity: .3;
}

/* Hover Picture */
#navbar li.home-icon:hover {
    background-image: url("Images/home_icon2.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.home-icon > a:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.rout-icon:hover {
    background-image: url("Images/dumbbell.jpg");
    background-size: contain; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.rout-icon > a:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.nutr-icon:hover {
    background-image: url("Images/fruit.png");
    background-size: contain; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.nutr-icon > a:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.abou-icon:hover {
    background-image: url("Images/about_icon.png");
    background-size: contain; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.abou-icon > a:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.cont-icon:hover {
    background-image: url("Images/contact_icon.png");
    background-size: contain; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.cont-icon > a:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

#main-footer {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Saturday Sans ICG Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > The navbar does not fill up the whole screen.

This is because you've set a fixed width for you navbar list items `width: 200px;`.

So to make it fill the screen width (assuming you'll always have five items), you could do something like this: (`100% / 5 = 20%`)

```
#navbar ul li {
    width: 20%;
    /* The rest of your styles */
}
```

Though this will also affect the Nutrition list items width as well, so you could add style for them specifically:

```
#navbar .nutr-icon li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will make the Nutrition list items as wide as the Nutrition item itself.

2. > The text in the navbar isn't in the center of their respective bubbles.

This is because you've set a `padding-right: 60px;` on the `a` tags in the navbar, which cause them to be shifted from the center. so just comment that out (or delete it)

```
#navbar a {
    color: #A9A9A9;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*padding-right: 60px;*/
}
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/OmarEinea/pen/LeyopR) of my changes.

Comment: `navbar width will always be 1000px` are you sure ? i advice to at least run the code and see. This is not true at all, we have block element and a block element always take 100% width. Here we have floating issue.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I did run the code and saw. you could see that my solution works in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/OmarEinea/pen/LeyopR) I linked, though it might not be the best solution.

Comment: am not talking about your solution or your code .. am talking about your explanation which is wrong and not logic : `This is because you've set a fixed width for you navbar list items width: 200px;, which means the navbar width will always be 1000px (as it has five items).` HTML/CSS doesn't work in this way

Comment: I've checked that and indeed it stays `1000px` wide if the screen can fit it, otherwise it breaks it into two rows (like in your solution).

Comment: 1) `nav` and `ul` are block element, which means they take 100% of the parent container whataver their content is. They are not inline or inline-block element to have their width fit the width of their content. 2) the `li` are floating element in his code and he's not clear floating properly that's why he's facing this issue. So i don't know what did you check and where you saw the 1000px value

Comment: I'm learning from you a lot, thank you! it's true that the `nav` and `ul` tags are of width 0, that's because there isn't anything in them (as all `li` tags are float). But I'm talking about the visual navbar, which is composed of those five `li` tags in a row (each `200px` that's why the accumulate to `1000px`).

Comment: No big deal, maybe my explanation isn't clear, and the whole use of float in this case is wrong. but hey I tried to come up with something that works :)

Comment: for me it's a big deal if the explanation is wrong/unclear ... a working solution is not only the intention. The main purpose is to provide the good explanation so that anyone who see your answer can understand. But if the explanation is wrong and the solution is working, it's not good at all as we may end with bad information especially for new coder.

Comment: Alright, I removed the part which mentions the width of the navbar. I hope the explanation makes more sense now :D

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to remove float and change it with `display:inline-block` then use `text-align:center` on the nav.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  font-family: 'Saturday Sans ICG Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Saturday Sans ICG Bold";
  src: url("Fonts/Saturday Sans ICG Bold.tff");
  src: url("Fonts/saturday_sans_icg_bold-webfont.woff");
}

#main-header {
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Saturday Sans ICG Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navbar a {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

#navbar ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align:center;
}

#navbar ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-top: 2px #f4f4f4 solid;
  border-bottom: 2px #f4f4f4 solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  position:relative;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
}

#navbar ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
}

#navbar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#navbar ul li ul li:hover {
  opacity: .3;
}


/* Hover Picture */

#navbar li.home-icon:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/home_icon2.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.home-icon>a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.rout-icon:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/dumbbell.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.rout-icon>a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.nutr-icon:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/fruit.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.nutr-icon>a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.abou-icon:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/about_icon.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.abou-icon>a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.cont-icon:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/contact_icon.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.cont-icon>a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#main-footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Saturday Sans ICG Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav id="navbar">
    <!--<div class="container">-->
    <ul>
      <li class="home-icon"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="rout-icon"><a href="#">Routines</a></li>
      <li class="nutr-icon"><a href="#">Nutrition</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Meals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Diet Plans</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Calorie Tracking</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="abou-icon"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="cont-icon"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--</div>-->
  </nav>

  <footer id="main-footer">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 Test</p>
  </footer>
```

Or you can use flex like this :

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  font-family: 'Saturday Sans ICG Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Saturday Sans ICG Bold";
  src: url("Fonts/Saturday Sans ICG Bold.tff");
  src: url("Fonts/saturday_sans_icg_bold-webfont.woff");
}

#main-header {
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Saturday Sans ICG Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navbar a {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

#navbar ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}

#navbar ul li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-top: 2px #f4f4f4 solid;
  border-bottom: 2px #f4f4f4 solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
}

#navbar ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

#navbar ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

#navbar ul li ul li:hover {
  opacity: .3;
}


/* Hover Picture */

#navbar li.home-icon:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/home_icon2.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.home-icon>a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.rout-icon:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/dumbbell.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.rout-icon>a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.nutr-icon:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/fruit.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.nutr-icon>a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.abou-icon:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/about_icon.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.abou-icon>a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#navbar li.cont-icon:hover {
  background-image: url("Images/contact_icon.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar li.cont-icon>a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#main-footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Saturday Sans ICG Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav id="navbar">
    <!--<div class="container">-->
    <ul>
      <li class="home-icon"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="rout-icon"><a href="#">Routines</a></li>
      <li class="nutr-icon"><a href="#">Nutrition</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Meals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Diet Plans</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Calorie Tracking</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="abou-icon"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="cont-icon"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--</div>-->
  </nav>

  <footer id="main-footer">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 Test</p>
  </footer>
```